# How to use theano.gradient.hessian? Example needed

Tags: python, theano, hessian-matrix

I tried the code below:

```
x=T.dvector('x')
y=T.dvector('y')
input=[x,y]
s=T.sum(x**2+y**2)
f=theano.gradient.hessian(s,wrt=input)
h=function(input,f)
```

Then I run it with following real values

```
x=[1,2]
y=[1,2]
h([x,y]
```

Then I encountered following error

```
TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "<ipython-input-115-32fd257c46ad>:7"  at index 0(0-based)', 'Wrong number of dimensions: expected 1, got 2 with shape (2L, 2L).')
```

I am new to python and am exploring Theano for building neural networks.

Answer (score 1):

`h` is a function that accepts two parameters. You are giving it a single parameter which is a list containing two elements.

Try changing `h([x,y])` to `h(x,y)`.