# Get jacobian of outputs with respect to inputs in keras

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, keras

I'd like to get the jacobian of dy/dx in keras, I'm using theano as the backend.

Comment: Please show your effort. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42792405/1586200) question is a good starting point. It discusses Jacobian and Hessian.

Comment: When using Theano backend you have access to a method (`theano.gradient.jacobian()`) for calculating the jacobian: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/gradient.html#theano.gradient.jacobian

Comment: Gotcha, I was trying theano.function([model.layers[0].input], T.jacobian(model.layers[-1].output.flatten(), model.layers[0].input)) but the output shape was weird. (number of items * output size, number of items, input size)

Comment: How can we compute it if the backend is tensorflow?